# writing a pkg-config file that supports `--static`

Tags: build, static-linking, pkg-config

I want to provide a pkg-config file that (additionally) supports static linking.

Usually you can do that with something like:

```
Libs: -L${libdir} -lfoo
Libs.private: -L${libdir} -lbar
Cflags: -I${includedir} -DFOO
```

which will yield:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags foo
-I/usr/local/include -DFOO
$ pkg-config --libs foo
-L/usr/local/lib -lfoo
$ pkg-config --static --cflags foo
-I/usr/local/include -DFOO
$ pkg-config --static --libs foo
-L/usr/local/lib -lfoo -lbar
```

Unfortunately, my library *foo* requires to use different pre-processor defines when linking dynamically/statically and also to link in a different version of the lib.

So the desired output would be:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags foo
-I/usr/local/include -DFOO_DYNAMIC
$ pkg-config --libs foo
-L/usr/local/lib -lfoo
$ pkg-config --static --cflags foo
-I/usr/local/include -DFOO_STATIC
$ pkg-config --static --libs foo
-L/usr/local/lib -lfoo_static
```

So the question is:

- is it possible to provide *different* CFLAGS/LIBS for the `static` variant rather than just *adding* on top of the dynamic variant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

A workaround is to provide a different .pc file, named foo-static.pc or something similar.

Comment: On stackoverflow it is appreciated to provide the "long answer" as well.

Answer (score 2):

Old question here, but the accepted answer is technically wrong. I haven't tested this, but I believe if you use the pkgconf instead of the original pkg-config, it supports a Cflags.private field. No, you can't pass an entirely different set of CFLAGS from the same .pc file, but that doesn't matter.

You can simply use Cflags.private in your .pc file. This will pass the normal CFLAGS as well, but you can fix that by additionally using an undefining flag. E.g.:

Cflags: -DFOO_DYNAMIC

Cflags.private: -UFOO_DYNAMIC -DFOO_STATIC